# TFS-Git 2013 and branching

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

We are using TFS-Git 2013 (the online version, visualstudio.com) as our source control, with visual studio 2013.
We want to keep doing what we were doing before switching to git on branching strategies.
We used to have one main trunk for development.
and then create a branch release for each release
So, for release 1 we will have Branch: release1
and so on for release 2, 3....
and our developers are used to create a separate directory for the main trunk, and for each branch.

Can that be done?
is there a documentation and training on how to do that?
I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The ALM Rangers are a great source of information on branching.

There is a [TFVC branching guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) and a "Git for TFVC Users" [coming soon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2014/02/22/what-s-cooking-in-the-alm-rangers-home.aspx).

Comment: As I said, "Git for TFVC Users" is coming soon, I'll update this when I see it released.